# Read until end of stream in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm fairly new to Haskell, and I'd like to keep reading lines from the console until the end of the stream, and outputting everything I get in upper case. So far, I've got

```
import Data.Char

main = myLoop

myLoop = do inp <- getLine
            if (inp == "x") 
              then putStrLn "Bye!"
              else do putStrLn(map toUpper inp)
                      myLoop
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to avoid the `if (inp == "x")` condition and replace it with an end of stream condition.

In short, I'm looking for Haskell's equivalent to `while (cin >> line)` in C++

Comment: You should select the answer from Dave4420 - it indicates people having the problem you describe which of the solutions actually answers it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This goes way beyond what you're really asking for, but I use this pattern a lot: `interact`:

```
myFun :: String -> String
myFun = ...

main = interact (unlines . myFun . lines)
```

Your function `myFun` will be executed against every line of standard input and the result sent to standard output.

Comment: I guess it's a ghci curiosity, but `main = interact (unlines . map (map toUpper) . lines) >> putStrLn "bye"` doesn't work inside ghci -- it's like `interact toUpper` -- but it does what Kshitij Mehta wants if you compile or use runhaskell

Comment: @applicative what doesn't work about it? The only weird thing I encountered is that instead of using CTRL-D to signal the end of input, you have to interrupt it with CTRL-C instead. The same goes for `ghc -e "interact (unlines . map (map toUpper) . lines) >> putStrLn \"bye\""`

Comment: Inside ghci, the first line "first line" looks like this `fFiIrRsStT  LLiInNeE`

Comment: @applicative that's your input mingling with the output in real time. If you go line by line instead you'll get the behavior you expect.

Comment: Yes, I knew that, what surprised me is the different behavior of the compiled version.

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you were saying. Yes, this is odd. I notice if you do `hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering` you get line-by-line behavior whichever version you choose. I echo your sentiment, it seems like a ghci curiosity (perhaps readline-related?).

Answer (score 19):

Use [`isEOF`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/System-IO.html#v:isEOF) from `System.IO`.

```
import System.IO (isEOF)
import Data.Char

main = myLoop

myLoop = do done <- isEOF
            if done
              then putStrLn "Bye!"
              else do inp <- getLine
                      putStrLn (map toUpper inp)
                      myLoop
```

Comment: It might be slightly better style to use `unless done $ do ...` since no meaningful computation is performed in the `done == True` branch.

Comment: Answers the question + gives a solution that works on really long files

Answer (score 11):

You could also just rely on lazy IO.

```
import Data.Char

main :: IO ()
main = do
   inp <- getContents
   let ls = lines inp
       upcased = map (map toUpper) ls
   mapM_ putStrLn upcased
```

Comment: This is great when I don't necessarily want to process the input one line at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `when` whose documentation can be found [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:when):

```
import System.IO (isEOF)
import Data.Char (toUpper)
import Control.Monad (forever, when)
import System.Exit (exitSuccess)
main = myLoop

myLoop = forever $ do
                done <- isEOF
                when done $ putStrLn "Bye!" >> exitSuccess
                inp <- getLine
                putStrLn (map toUpper inp)
                myLoop
```

Otherwise, the answer is identical to [the one by @dave4420](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754864/165753).

Comment: An extra difference is you also use `forever`, so actually it is a double infinite loop.