# Read list of numbers in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and I was working in a problem where I had to remove repeated consecutive numbers from a list, so I wrote this program.

```
destutter::[Integer] -> [Integer]
destutter [] = []
destutter (fst:snd:t) | fst == snd = destutter (snd : t)
destutter (h:t) = [h] ++ (destutter t)
```

It works fine for the input test that I had which was a list

```
input = [200, 271, 305, 305, 180]
```

now I have a text file with a lot of inputs and I need to use my function on it, if it was in C++ I would do something like:

```
while(cin>> x)
    v.push_back(x);
destutter(x);
```

But I'm completely new to Haskell and I have no idea how I would do that on this language. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754794/read-until-end-of-stream-in-haskell) answer on stack overflow but was not able to modify the code for my use, so if someone could give a noob a hand I would be very thankful. My text file has the following structure:

```
260
221
235
268
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `getContents` to get **all** input from `stdin`. It does so lazily, so don't worry about running out of memory.

Then separate it into lines with `lines` (or write your own function to divide it into lines for practice). This makes a `[String]` with each list element being a line in the input.

Then `map` `read` over each element (or write your own `map` and `read` functions for practice) to turn each element from a `String` into an `Integer`.

Now you have an `[Integer]` that you can `destutter`.

```hs
destutter::[Integer] -> [Integer]
destutter [] = []
destutter (fst:snd:t) | fst == snd = destutter (snd : t)
destutter (h:t) = [h] ++ (destutter t)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  userInput <- getContents
  let numbers = map read (lines userInput) :: [Integer]
  print $ destutter numbers
```

#### A few notes on improving `destutter` a little and a lot

You shouldn't use this if you're writing an assignment for school (your `destutter` definitely works), but as far as `destutter` goes, there are a few things to help your learning.

A minor stylistic issue is that `x` and `xs` (or `y` and `ys` or anything of that pattern) are used for head and tail rather than `h` and `t`.

`[x] ++ xs` is harder to read (and more expensive) than `x:xs`, so your third pattern for `destutter` can be done like this:

```hs
destutter (x:xs) = x:destutter xs
```

`(:)` is useful for detaching elements from the front of a list in patterns **and** for attaching elements to the front of a list outside of patterns.

---

Don't worry about this so much now, but later on, after you get the hang of writing functions from scratch, you'll begin to use prewritten functions like `Data.List.group`, which is quite similar to `destutter` as it groups equal neighbors in a list into their own sublist. If you take the first element (`head`) of each sublist (they're all equal, so one's as good as another), it does `destutter`:

```
import Data.List (group)

destutter :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
destutter xs = map head (group xs)
```

So, basically, it turns `[1, 2, 2, 3]` into `[[1], [2, 2], [3]]`, then it takes the first element of each sublist to get `[1, 2, 3]`.

One thing to take from that is that you already know how to write a function (`destutter`) quite similar to those that they include with Haskell.

Comment: I agree that `[x] ++ xs` is harder to read here than `x:xs`, but it isn't more expensive: with optimizations on, GHC is smart enough to compile them both to the exact same code. I agree with the refactoring here, but I mention it because another common place you see this is `prefix ++ [val] ++ suffix`, and in that situation I think that is more readable than `prefix ++ val:suffix` because the former is more symmetric and does not depend on operator precedence. (Upvoted, though. This answer covers a lot of ground in an excellent way. Nice work!)

Comment: You might cover `interact` as well. `do {in <- getContents; print (f in)}` is more easily written as `interact (show . f)`. Thus, `main = interact $ show . destutter . map read . lines`